# NoReverseMatch at / error on production server, but no issues in local

Tags: python, django, path, gunicorn, dev-to-production

I added a tos.html page to my django app, and it works great in local, but once I pull it into production, it shows this

```
NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'tos' not found. 'tos' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://www.flythecoop.io/
Django Version:     2.2.6
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'tos' not found. 'tos' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Exception Location:     /home/reviews/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 673
Python Executable:  /home/reviews/venv/bin/python3.8
Python Version:     3.8.0
Python Path:    

['/home/reviews/venv/bin',
 '/home/reviews/reviews',
 '/home/reviews/venv/lib/python38.zip',
 '/home/reviews/venv/lib/python3.8',
 '/home/reviews/venv/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/home/reviews/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages']

Server time:    Tue, 11 Feb 2020 01:02:33 +0000
```

It's in my base.html file

```
63    </body>
64     <footer>
65     <br>
66    <p class="text-center">
67     <a class="btn btn-link btn-sm" href="{% url 'tos' %}" role="button">Terms of Service </a>
68     <a class="btn btn-link btn-sm" href="{% url 'about' %}" role="button">About </a>
69     <a class="btn btn-link btn-sm" href="{% url 'faq' %}" role="button">FAQ </a></p>
70  </footer> 
71  </html>
```

Here is my urls.py in the pages app

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('tos/', views.TosPageView.as_view(), name='tos'),
    path('about/', views.AboutPageView.as_view(), name='about'),
    path('faq/', views.FaqPageView.as_view(), name='faq'),
]
```

Here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
# Create your views here.

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'

class TosPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'tos.html'

class AboutPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'about.html'

class FaqPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'faq.html'
```

Here's the project level urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

#from boards import views


urlpatterns = [
    # This path for pages as static
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('boards/', include('boards.urls')),
   # path('boards/', include('boards.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

]
```

I've looked through other questions like it, but most are from years ago and using different versions. I think i must be missing something obvious but it's been awhile since I added a page.

Comment: Is `tos` the only page that isn't working in prod? or do others; `about` or `faq` have similar problems?

Comment: both have similar problems, as I'm adding those pages at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, i just had to do `sudo supervisorctl restart reviews` for the app and i guess it started serving the new pages